# What are counterfactual objectives?

Tags: machine-learning, counterfactuals

What is a simple-to-understand definition/explanation for counterfactual objectives in Machine Learning?

I heard this term in this 3 minutes paper presentation https://youtu.be/TOpJ4g9v-H4.